# My texturepack folder in minecraft doesn't exist. (Mac computer)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I've tried restarting Finder, showing hidden folder codes, and the "Open resource pack folder" ingame button doesn't work; I have a sneaking suspicion my computer doesn't have the folder at all. It's a MacBook Pro, if that helps at all. If anyone has any methods, I would love to try them out.

[image: Attempt to search after using the "chflags nohidden ~/Library/" and "defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE" codes in Finder.]

This is what my labelled texture pack folder looks like:

[image: texturepackfolder]

Comment: Have you tried creating a folder called `resourcepacks`?

Comment: What Minecraft version are you using?

Comment: That would be 1.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In minecraft 1.5 and before, the folder was for texturepacks was `texturepacks`. Now, in 1.6 and above, it is called resourcepacks. Therefore the folder is now `resourcepacks`. See the minecraft wiki page on texturepacks [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Texturepacks#Installing_a_texture_pack) and the page for resourcepacks [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack#Behavior).

Comment: I'll check it out. I was mostly trying to add a mod, but it'd be nice to know how to download a texture as well.

Comment: @Accaila What does unregistered mean? It says that on your profile page

Comment: I haven't verified my email yet. I have now. @TheCodingMonster

Comment: Ok. I hope you stay on at Arqade and not leave once you get your answer. Mabye go edit some questions to get reputation.

Comment: I was wondering how that works... I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I've found the folder, my problem is now that texture packs placed in the correct folder don't appear ingame to be selected.

---

Thanks to [RavenM](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13828/ravenm) for suggesting to simply make a folder. That worked beautifully.